# limit clause in select count() query is not working as I expected

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE id = ? && UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) > ? LIMIT 10");
                            $query->bindValue(1, $id);
                            $query->bindValue(2, $timestamp);
                            $query->execute();
                            $count = $query->fetchColumn();
                            var_dump($count);
```

`var_dump($count)` is displaying a number higher than the limit clause. Is it not possible to limit the result in a select count query?

Comment: Aggregate function without `group by` returns one row only so limit does not help here. However you may provide some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually how your query works and is a normal behaviour. Using `LIMIT` you will not limit the `count` or `sum` but only the returned rows. So your query will return more rows as stated in your `LIMIT` clause. And since your query actually returns only all possible row, applying a (non-zero) limit has no effect on the results.

`Limit` just limit record to show at a time.`Count` Will returned all the possible rows

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, I thought that was probably why but could not find any documentation stating that.

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM table
WHERE id = ? && UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) > ?
LIMIT 10
```

Only returns one row because it is an aggregation query with no `group by`.  The `limit` is not really used.

Perhaps you want this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM table t
      WHERE id = ? && UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) > ?
      LIMIT 10
     ) t;
```